# Change image with <picture> and js

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, laravel

I have a small slider that switches the `preview` image to the `main` image. It works fine now

*blade.php*

```
<div class="custom-carousel-section">
  <div class="custom-container">
    <div class="custom-carousel">
      @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
      <div class="custom-carousel__title">
        @if($loop->first)
          <span>{{ $article_block_image->title }}</span>
        @endif
      </div>
      @endforeach @endif
      @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
      <div class="main-image">
      @if($loop->first)
          <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
      @endif
      </div>
      @endforeach @endif
      <div class="img-to-select">
        @if(!empty($article_block_images)) @foreach($article_block_images as $article_block_image)
        <div @if($loop->first) class="img-to-select__item  selected" @else class="img-to-select__item" @endif>
          <img src="{{ $article_block_image->preview_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}" data-main-src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}">
        </div>
        @endforeach @endif
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*js*

```
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
$('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').data('main-src'));
$('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

But I still have a picture `mobile_image`, and I want the `mobile_image` to change instead of `main_image` at the maximum size of 576px, for this I use `<picture>`

I change my code to like this

```
<div class="main-image">
@if($loop->first)
<picture>
  <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
  <source srcset="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
  <img src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" alt="{{ $article_block_image->image_alt }}" title="{{ $article_block_image->image_title }}" data-title="{{ $article_block_image->title }}">
</picture>
@endif
</div>
```

But my slider just stops working

The main image eventually changes to mobile, but the slider itself does not switch

In this case, the preview images also echo, but the main image itself does not change

My slider essentially works like this

> https://jsfiddle.net/a9yvdu75/

I just need to put what in the `main-image` class in `<picture>` and change the image depending on the screen size

Comment: Have you tried initializing the slider again after you switch to ```<picture>```?

Comment: @VladSolomon I don't have initialization here, this is all the code with which the slider worked

Comment: So when you reach the 576px breakpoint and the images get replace by the mobile ones, the slider just stops working?

Comment: @VladSolomon it does not work at all, more precisely, it clicks on the preview iamges, but the main image does not change, but at the same time `<picture>` works, and at the required size it replaces the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line is problematic:

```js
$('.main-image > img').attr('src', $(this).children('img').data('main-src'));
```

The symbol `>` means that `img` must be an immediate child of `.main-image`. So you have to choose one of the selectors `$('.main-image img')` or `$('.main-image > picture > img')`. But that still won't work because...

The second problem is that you don't fully understand how `<picture>` works. The browser chooses `<source>` to display itself, based on the rules in `media`. And the same `<img>` is only for browsers, which doesn't support `<picture>`.
So setting `.attr('src'` only works if you remove all `<source>`.

Also in many places you use `.children('img')`.

So if you want to do such substitutions, you have to remove responsive image selection.

I believe the quickest solution for you is to [use an alternative syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Multimedia_and_embedding/Responsive_images#resolution_switching_different_sizes). (You will still need to programmatically remove `srcset, sizes`)

```html
<img srcset="elva-fairy-480w.jpg 480w,
             elva-fairy-800w.jpg 800w"
     sizes="(max-width: 600px) 480px,
            800px"
     src="elva-fairy-800w.jpg"
     alt="Elva dressed as a fairy">
```

#### Another alternative is to swap the entire `.main-image` section. eg.:

```html
<div class="main-image">
  <picture>
    <!-- placeholder, insert the correct HTML yourself  -->
  </picture>
</div>
```

And using JS like:

```js
$('.main-image > picture').html(`
  <source media="(max-width: 799px)" srcset="elva-480w-close-portrait.jpg">
  <source media="(min-width: 800px)" srcset="elva-800w.jpg">
  <img src="elva-800w.jpg" alt="Chris standing up holding his daughter Elva">
`)
```

You must store "desktop" and mobile sources in the thumbnail.

```html
<div @if($loop->first) class="img-to-select__item  selected" @else class="img-to-select__item" @endif>
  <img src="{{ $article_block_image->preview_image }}" 
    ... 
    data-main-src="{{ $article_block_image->main_image }}" 
    data-mobile-src="{{ $article_block_image->mobile_image }}"
  >
</div>
```

The rest is just tedious gluing of strings.

##### //EDIT: one of possible solutions.

```js
$('.img-to-select__item').click(function () {
  $('.img-to-select__item').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  let mainSrc = $(this).children('img').data('main-src')
  let mobileSrc = $(this).children('img').data('mobile-src')
  let title = $(this).children('img').attr('title')
  let alt = $(this).children('img').attr('alt')
  $('.main-image > picture').html(`
    <source srcset="{$mobileSrc}" media="(max-width: 576px)" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
    <source srcset="{$mainSrc}" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
    <img src="{$mainSrc}" alt="{$alt}" title="{$title}">
  `);
  $('.custom-carousel__title > span').html($(this).children('img').attr('data-title'));
});
```

Remember, in JS you work with already generated HTML (provided data), you do not have access to PHP variables.

Comment: okay, thanks, here on the second option I will then have `data-main-src` and `data-mobile-src`, how to determine then where is which one in the script?

Comment: Can you make jsfiddle with `picure` and 2 sources?

Comment: yes, only a little later, if you don't mind, I'll try to do it according to the first option, maybe the second won't come in handy at all

Comment: Well, let's say I receive a couple of pictures, main, mobile and a preview, I don't quite understand what should be in the script in this case https://jsfiddle.net/17trajhx/

Comment: heh... fixed https://jsfiddle.net/kwxg49qz/2/ (and I hope I was right in the JS template syntax)

Comment: thanks) I will leave the resolved issue, what if I will write, while I just have no opportunity to check

Comment: Ok, I'll try to check in on Monday.